# How to make a TextView flash its background when clicked?

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have like 10+ textview embedded in a scrollview to give a ListView effect(I don't want to use a ListView here for some particular reasons).

Some details about the textview is that it has a background which is an image.

So my question is when I click on a particular textview among the 10+ views taht I have, I want to animate the background like the ones in a native ListView. If this is possible can someone provide some pointers please?

If not animating the background can we atleast animate the borders of the clicked textview?

Thanks,
Sana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your TextView's background to state list selector drawable such as:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_pressed_background" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/your_normal_background" />
</selector>
```

You save the above XML in the res/drawable directory and reference it in your TextView like an other resource.

Based on the state of your TextView, android will select the background drawable. When your TextView is pressed, the pressed background will be drawn. When it is not, your normal background will be drawn.